# e.target removing wrong button?

Tags: javascript

So my code should remove the text and button that have the same data-index but right now it's only deleting the `div` with the correct data-index

I tried to do `e.target.remove();`
but that removes the latest button and not the one that was pressed

```
let div;
let k = 0;
let o = 0;

function addBookToLibrary(bookToAdd) {
    myLibrary.push(bookToAdd);
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = Object.values(bookToAdd);
    div.dataset.index = k;
    k++;
    main.appendChild(div);
    
    const remove = document.createElement("button");
    remove.textContent = "remove";
    remove.dataset.index = o;
    o++;
    main.appendChild(remove);
    remove.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let dataIndex = e.target.dataset.index;
        let element = document.querySelector(`div[data-index="${dataIndex}"]`);
        element.remove();
        myLibrary.splice(dataIndex, 1);
    })
}
```

Comment: Well... you're only querying for the div, so why should other things also get removed?

Comment: for example e.target.style.opacity = 0; works but obviously im not doing that

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Comment: if i console.log(e.target) it logs the button element

Comment: @VitaliyRayets that doesn't work or it only works if im not removing the div also